# How to remove ending dot from numbering

Tags: koma-script, polyglossia

With koma I can remove the ending dot with `numbers=noenddot` option. But when I add polyglossia package, it stops to work.

```
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{scrreport}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt{Courier New}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\chapter{F}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Исходные данные для рассматриваемой задачи}
    \centering
    \label{tabl:1}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Номер & ~~~~$X$~~~~ & ~~~~$Y$~~~~ & ~~~~$R$~~~~ & ~~~~Цвет~~~~          \\
        \hline
        1     & 100         & 170         & 30          & \color{red} красный   \\
        2     & 100         & 90          & 60          & \color{yellow} жёлтый \\
        3     & 230         & 250         & 50          & \color{blue} синий    \\
        4     & 130         & 240         & 60          & \color{green} зелёный \\
        5     & 300         & 130         & 30          & \color{green} зелёный \\
        6     & 200         & 150         & 90          & \color{red} красный   \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I get:
[image]

I want:
[image]

Comment: Must you use `polyglossia`? It seems to work as desired using `\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}`.

Comment: Yes, I use Xelatex.

Comment: So? Babel has no issues with `XeLaTeX`. PS: The correct name of the class is **scrreprt**.

Comment: I need hyphenation and custom dates.

Comment: Since babel can handle those without issues, I fail to see your point. But if you really must, try something like `\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\thechapter~}`

Comment: Of course, it's up to you to decide which package to use, but the assumption "if I use XeTeX I *must* use `polyglossia`" is wrong. `Babel` is fully compatible with XeTeX and LuaTeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default package `polyglossia` uses option `forceheadingpunction=true` for Russian. So you have to set the russian language option `forceheadingpunctuation` to `false`:

```latex
\setdefaultlanguage[forceheadingpunctuation=false]{russian}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{scrreport}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[forceheadingpunctuation=false]{russian}% <- changed
\setotherlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt{Courier New}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\chapter{F}
\begin{table}
  \caption{Исходные данные для рассматриваемой задачи}
  \centering
  \label{tabl:1}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Номер & ~~~~$X$~~~~ & ~~~~$Y$~~~~ & ~~~~$R$~~~~ & ~~~~Цвет~~~~          \\
    \hline
    1     & 100         & 170         & 30          & \color{red} красный   \\
    2     & 100         & 90          & 60          & \color{yellow} жёлтый \\
    3     & 230         & 250         & 50          & \color{blue} синий    \\
    4     & 130         & 240         & 60          & \color{green} зелёный \\
    5     & 300         & 130         & 30          & \color{green} зелёный \\
    6     & 200         & 150         & 90          & \color{red} красный   \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]